# error when comparing values from an integer ArrayList to a variable Integer

Tags: java

i was trying to get values from an integer array list using 'get' method and compare it to an integer variable, but when i attempt to do so the compiler throws an error.
the code and error i receive are posted below.

Java Code:

```
public boolean isExistGuess(int guess, ArrayList arraylist) {
    boolean found = false;
    for (int i=0; i < arraylist.size(); i++) {
        if (arraylist.get(i) == guess)
            found = true;
}
}
```

Error Message:

```
incompatible operand types Object and Int
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing **ArrayList arraylist** as a parameter, since you have not explicitly specified the type, its arraylist of Object by default.

So, when you are doing **arraylist.get(i)**, you get an object back.

Try passing, ArrayList of Integer as a paremeter

```
ArrayList<Integer> arraylist
```

Answer (score 6):

That's because ArrayList is not a generic one in your case.

Use

```
ArrayList<Integer>
```

instead in method signature

Answer (score 1):

When you don't provide a type for your list, it becomes a "raw" type - effectively treated as `ArrayList<Object>`.

You could change your method to use a typed list (note that it is poor practice to specify the particular list implementation - just `List` is best):

```
public boolean isExistGuess(int guess, List<Integer> list) {
```

But your entire method is unnecessary, because Lists have a `contains()` method that does exactly what you've coded. Use it like thus:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Populate your lust, then later:

```
if (list.contains(guess))
```